# SQL: Select unique dates, total in that date, and total in that date AND another parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

In SQL I am trying to get a return of 3 categories.

1. Unique Dates
2. Number of people that visit on the day in 1.
3. Number of times visit on the day in 1 AND visit on a specific date

I have this for my SQL

```
SELECT
DISTINCT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, visit_date)) as theday, 
(SELECT count(DISTINCT visit_id)) as uniques, 
(SELECT count(DISTINCT visit_id) 
FROM visitors 
WHERE visit_id IN (
SELECT DISTINCT visit_id 
FROM visitors 
WHERE (visit_date >= '2014-03-29 00:00:00.000' 
AND visit_date <= '2014-03-30 00:00:00.000')
)
) as visited_again
FROM visitors
WHERE visit_date >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, visit_date))
ORDER BY theday DESC;
```

And it works great for giving me #1 and #2 but the third one is only giving me one unique number that repeats for each date.

The SQL above returns results that look like:

```
   theday    |    uniques    |    visited_again
-------------+---------------+------------------
2014-03-30   |    900000     |    84450
2014-03-29   |    789433     |    84450
2014-03-28   |    823010     |    84450
2014-03-27   |    901101     |    84450
2014-03-26   |    773556     |    84450
2014-03-25   |    345789     |    84450
```

Comment: Which is it, MySQL or SQL Server?  You probably mean less-than (`<`) for your upper bound (or you'll include midnight on the next day, too).  Could we get sample source data and desired results?  Obviously not something large enough to generate _those_ results... And do you have a calendar table?

Comment: can you give the sql to create the table and insert some sample rows ? you can use sqlfiddle to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spot where you try to count the repeat visits, the individual visit_id values from the outer query are no longer available, so you can't look at each visit_id value separately. Try this:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME;
SET @d = '2014-03-30 00:00:00.000';

WITH V(visit_id,theday,special_date_flag) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    visit_id,
    visit_date,
    CASE WHEN visit_id IN (
      SELECT visit_id FROM visitors
      WHERE visit_date >= @d AND visit_date < @d+1
      --note change to select 1, not 2 dates here!
    ) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
  FROM visitors
)
SELECT
  theday, 
  count(visit_id) as uniques,
  count(special_date_flag) as visited_again
FROM V
WHERE thedate >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' 
GROUP BY theday
ORDER BY theday DESC
```

This query first creates a virtual table of (visit_id, theday) values, which has a third column for each row to indicate if the particular visit_id is one of the ones for the special date.

There are other ways to do this - you really only need the flag for each visit_id, not (visit_id,theday) pair, but this was easier to write.